# grunt-angular-templates cache all templates

Tags: angularjs, templates, gruntjs

So I ran into an issue when trying to use toastr as a global error notification system in my angular application.
This was logged as an issue with angular-toastr and the proposed solution was to push all templates into the templatecache. Apparently this is a good thing to do and after reading up on why, I have to agree.

My problem is that I am really new to grunt (only just installed it today) and although I have now managed to successfully set up my gruntfile.js and run some tasks (minification, concatination, etc) using grunt-angular-templates is a mystery to me.

I have set up my gruntfile like this:

```
ngtemplates: {
    options: {
        module: 'project',
    },
    dist: {
        src: [
            'wwwroot/lib/angular-toastr/**.html'
        ],
        dest: 'wwwroot/js/templates.js'
    }
}
```

But my templates file that is generated is empty.
I assume this is because scripts are creating in the JS files.
Does anyone know how I can get access to the them so I can add them to the cache?

Comment: When you run the grunt command add --verbose onto the end, this will output a lot of helpful information that may help you track down the error. I would guess it is not finding your files. Double check your filepath. Do you need a '/' at the front?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your source files are not being 'seen'.  This worked for me with the following configuration and I am using a similar structure where the output is in a **wwwroot/lib** folder.  I am also using the cwd (source directory option).  Make sure that the templates are copied to the wwwroot folder before the grunt task is executed.  I have other grunt tasks that 'clean' the **wwwroot/lib** folder so I store my source html(s) in another folder.  That may also help if you are not doing that.

If all else fails, run in verbose -V (like alex said). The task source file is in the following location.  You can also add additional debug in this file to further trouble shoot.

> node_modules\grunt-angular-templates\tasks\angular-templates.js

```
this.files.forEach(function(file) {
  if (!file.src.length) {
    grunt.log.warn('No templates found');
  }
```

This is the setup we use.

### Project structure

#### Source

project/assets/templates/admin/partials/(html files here)

#### Output

project/wwwroot/lib/templates(html files here)

#### Grunt Task

```
   ngtemplates:  {
        app:        {
            cwd:      'assets/templates',
            src:      '**/partials/*.html',
            dest: 'assets/templates/partials.js',
            options: {
                module: 'cms.admin'
            }
        }
    },
```

#### The Output Generates

```
angular.module('cms.admin').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  'use strict';

  $templateCache.put('Admin/partials/navmenu.template.html',
    "<nav class=\"navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top\">\r" +
    "</nav>"
  );

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably lies with your src: wwwroot/lib/angular-toastr/**.html

Maybe try using this grunt plugin, it's easy to use and does the same thing.
https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js

```
grunt.initConfig({
  html2js: {
    options: {
      // custom options, see below
    },
    main: {
      src: ['src/**/*.tpl.html'],
      dest: 'tmp/templates.js'
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the task individually like this: grunt ngtemplates -v. The -v argument stands for verbose mode. You should get the filenames that have been read. If there are no files being read, you might have a file path problem.

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity or to avoid the rabbit whole, you can also manually push the template to the cache so you can test the toastr issue.

1. Go to http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/
2. Convert the html to javascript
3. Use the output in the following code to cache manually.

   ```
   var strVar = "";
   strVar += "";
   strVar += "<div class=\" container-fluid wrapper-md\">";
   strVar += "    <h3>Title<\/h3>";
   strVar += "    <div id=\"markupArea\"> <\/div>";
   strVar += "   ";
   strVar += "<\/div>";
   strVar += "";

   angular.module('cms.admin').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
     'use strict';

     $templateCache.put('<CacheKEy>',strVar );
     }]);
   ```

Comment: This is not a considerable solution at all. We are using grunt to automate the process of development, not to fix thing manually

Comment: My point is to the initial issue was the inability to use toastr and the suggestion of putting the 'toastr' template in the cache.  My suggestion, since he is new to grunt was to try it manually first.  When I was new to this, I spent half a day trying to get grunt to work and I really only needed to 2 templates cached to see the actual issue.  Sometimes it is better to do it manually fix the issue, then automate it for all so that one doesn't add another level of errors to the mix.  That is all I was saying and I don't see your question.

Comment: I understand your intention, but I am not able to withdraw my down vote, because you did not make any change in the post. Pls make note in the post